# What does Phonegap local storage return if not set?

Tags: javascript, android, phonegap

Me and my team are developing a Phonegap app, and are encountering some issues. One of our functions looks like this:

```
var email = localStorage.getItem("email");
if (email != "" && email.type != undefined) {
    //Do stuffs
} else {
    //Do other stuffs
};
```

But, despite the local storage item 'email' being set to my email, it still executes the contents of the else statement, not the main if block. Maybe the answer is right under our noses, we just don't know (its 6 am here, very tired), so any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could log it: `console.log(localStorage.getItem("email"))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `email` will always return `null` if not set. I recommend just doing:

```
var email = localStorage.getItem("email");
 if (email !== null) {
   //Do stuffs
 } else {
   //Do other stuffs 
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try like this.

```
var email = window.localStorage.getItem("email");
```

Answer (score 0):

In general I believe `localStorage.getItem` returns `null` if it is unset. So you should be able to just do

```
var email = localStorage.getItem("email");
if (email) {
    //Do stuffs
} else {
    //Do other stuffs
};
```

Note that the empty string `""` is falsy (evaluates as false) in JavaScript.